# Angular js ng-class not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to do a pagination for my list of informations. Currently, there is two buttons which are `previous` and `next` button. The `previous` button is working but the `next` button is working but its continously working. Actually, I want it to be disabled once the end of the list has been reached. But now I can still click on the next button.

How do I solve this bug?

This is my pagination code:

```
<div ng-show="filteredItems > 0">

<ul class="pagination" page="currentPage">
    <li ng-class="{disabled: currentPage == 1}">
        <a href ng-click="prevPage()">« Prev</a>
    </li>

    <li ng-class="{disabled: currentPage == totalItems - 1}">
        <a href ng-click="nextPage()">Next »</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is my controller.js code:

```
$scope.nextPage = function () {
    if ($scope.currentPage < $scope.totalItems - 1) {
            $scope.currentPage++;
            console.log($scope.totalItems);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working [plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/A8HllaklSFhm19EPNZgk?p=preview)

Move the `ngClick` from `a` to `li` **OR** move the `ngClass` to `a`. For the first case:

```
<li ng-class="{disabled: currentPage == totalItems - 1}" ng-click="nextPage()">
    <a>Next »</a>
</li>
```

And this is assuming you have a class defined called `disabled`. If not, define it as follows:

```css
.disabled {
    opacity: 0.5;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: move the ng-click to the li containing the anchor tag

Comment: i guess the problem is in the totalItems

Comment: my currentPage value is 1 and my totalItems value is 1000

Comment: exactly, the condition is never getting true and thats why the `disable` class isn't getting applied.

Comment: Quotes aren't needed around `disabled`; it's a Javascript object literal, in which keys work just fine unquoted (within limits).

Comment: Thanks @deceze for the info. Never realized that.

Comment: @anonymous5671 I added a plunker in the answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `totalitems - 1` with `totalitems.length - 1`.

Comment: can you make  js fiddle for it

Answer (score 0):

try this 
ng-class="{'disabled': currentPage == totalItems - 1}